# X hours to schedule

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

I want to explain how many hours a student has on their balance so they can use these hours for scheduling lessons. It's not a complete sentence, rather a short notice about the state of their balance. Is the statement "X hours to schedule" grammatical and clear?

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you're saying is that a student buys a certain number of hours' tuition, lessons which they can then schedule at their convenience.

If this is the case, then in order to avoid miscontruing the *to schedule* as a preposition+noun rather than as a verb *to schedule,* I would introduce an adverb like *still:*

> 27 hours still to schedule

An alternative might describe the hours with an adjective or adjectival participle:

> 27 hours available (out of 40 purchased)
> 27 hours unscheduled

Any shortening introduces some ambiguity, and if a verb like *are* can be retained then that would make things clearer. It may be that the context does not require this as it's clear enough.

> 27 hours are available

Comment: Some good options there. The other I'd consider is "27 hours to be scheduled".